# Wrong insert in Oracle

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, oracle-apex

I have an oracle apex application.

I'm an Iranian, my application has to be right to left direction.

I have a page for data loading; it takes an Excel file and stores its data into the database.

Now the problem is it can't recognize the date column correctly. Even when I set format mask for the column insert wrong and wired data in database.

For example in Excel file, a date is `2022-07-08` but after inserting into the corresponding column, it is `30-09-2648`.

I try this page in another application that is not right to left direction and it works correctly.

A try to change direction of page using css property but it still doesn't work.

Please help me

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] that allows us to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should convert it to Persian date using `nls_calendar` parameter when you wanna insert it into the table because oracle didn't do it automatically.

```
to_date('2022-07-08', nls_calendar='persian')
```